# GEE Filters some tiles out

Tags: raster, google-earth-engine, tiles, filter, sentinel-2

I have code that creates rasters from polygons based on statistics of NDVI.
My problem is that for some reason, when the polygons are wide spreaded, the raster creation occurs only for some plots, but when I manually checl the plots that the raster wasn't created for them, it does create raster, meaning, there is avilable image but no raster is created and they are filteres out for some reason.

[image]

Example: 
https://code.earthengine.google.com/2a06f5e4409c2d5a5f36b0cb68053a41

In this example I have checked and found that all the plots suppose to have available image from 04/05/2020.

- plots -> the original polygon layer that is widely spread. When I run this, I get the raster only for few polygons.
- manually gee -> one manually drawn polygon, based on polygon that didn't get raster result from the original layer, when run this this polygon do get the calculation.

[image]

- manually gee2 -> another demonstration.
- manually gee 3 -> very far away polygon, I am not sure why this one didn't get the raster result.

**My end goal: that the raster calculation will happen for all the polygons based on the date, and not only based on one tile.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you plot the geometry of the original image, you would have seen that it simply doesn't cover all your geometries.

Return from your function:

```
  return ee.Image([betMEAN, ltNEG, gtPOS])
    .selfMask()  // Mask 0's
    .multiply(ee.Image([1, 2, 3])) // Assign values to the classes
    .reduce(ee.Reducer.firstNonNull()) // Pick first class
    .addBands(imageNDVI); // add original image NDVI
```

And add the geometry of that image to the map:

```
Map.addLayer(ndviClassImg.select('NDVI').geometry(),{color: 'red'},'geometry iamge');
print(ndviClassImg)
```

[image]

You'd probably best make a daily composite of all images present for the day of interest. Replace this line:

```
  var listOfImages =(withNDVI.toList(withNDVI.size()));
  var MyImage=ee.Image(withNDVI.first());
```

By this:

```
  var MyImage = withNDVI.mosaic();
```

[Link code](https://code.earthengine.google.com/14d2e24630707195a453c8aa2c80913d)